# Using WinForms way of grabbing input in XNA game

Tags: winforms, input, xna

Originally the question was *"How do WinForms capture and process user input"*, but since I want to use that for my XNA game, well, you can see the title.

I'd like to never miss a key stroke in my game, but XNA's default way of updating user input is dependent on framerate, and Nuclex.Input doesn't care which <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I press, doesn't detect some keys (including <kbd>F10</kbd>, left <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and <kbd>Pause</kbd>), so they won't work for me.

Is it possible to implement the same way of capturing user input in an XNA game, as the one used in WinForms applications, and how?

Comment: Nuclex.Input is *exactly* what you want.  It uses the exact same mechanism as Winforms.  "Doesn't work for all the keys" is hopelessly vague.  Just alter the Nuclex source code to fix your problem, what ever it may be.

Comment: It doesn't detect Alt keys correctly. How am I supposed to do key combinations without it? I couldn't find a way to modify the source code to fit my needs, so I'm asking if there is some basic way to grab all keys, so I could write a similar implementation by myself. I think the question is clear as day — winforms use some event based input system, and that's what I need for my game so it doesn't miss key strokes between frames.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Nuclex.Input. Perhaps it's because those are especially *systemy* keys. You still haven't said why you need such astoundingly responsive input - especially for those keys in particular!

Comment: Mod keys play an important role in my game (at least they're supposed to), as there are so, so many actions one can perform. I was surprised to find out that my friends and people who got a test build mapped some really unusual controls, and some of them used left alt for jump, which didn't work so well. Honestly, I'm so frustrated that I can't just make any key at least on my minimalistic keyboard work as good as it would in any other normal game, where you can do anything with your keys. I want that in my game too! :<

Comment: @HansPassant Where can I get an example of the Nuclex Input? It seems that the site is down.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/